# View Xml in Awesomium

Tags: c#, xml, awesomium

In Google Chrome, when you open an xml file, you get a formatted (pretty) view of the xml if there is no stylesheet referenced in the xml file itself.

I simply want to do this in my application, which uses Awesomium.

I am using the `Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl`

I don't want to roll my own if I can avoid it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing this in an internal tool for my development team.  I format the XML with an xsl that colors and indents everything, then update the web control with the resulting HTML.

Check out this link for formatting XML, the CSS styles are built in, so you can update styles colors as you wish
See the "XML to HTML Verbatim Formatter with Syntax Highlighting" project on this page.
http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/

Comment: I will mark this as answer. Do you know why a processing instruction at the top of my xml pointing to the xsl you mention (the wrapper) is not working? I mean, does Awesomium recognize that processing instruction? Otherwise, I'll have to use xml.xslt namespace, which is fine, just harder to do. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Toddmo, no idea.